# Parsing html document in java

Tags: document

I want to know how is possible to load and traverse a document from URL. I want to load a document from URL and being able to select basically html elements by tag name or class name or ID.
Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out a Jsoup library. You should be able to extract data by tags using it.

Comment: Looks what I want. Thank you